# .net core 2.0 MVC App - HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

So since I have introduced EntityFramework Core into my application and added migrations in order to create the database, my application no longer starts. I get the following error page:

> The application process failed to start
>   The application process started but then stopped
>   The application process started but failed to listen on the configured port

The application stops itself running after a few seconds thus making debugging tricky. I have followed some answers from other questions but still no luck.

Any suggestions in order to try and fix this?

I am using .netCore 2.0.6  (following is in my csproj file)

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.6" />
```

I am using Visual Studio 2017, here is the last line of the output window before the application terminates:

> Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured): {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.Message","time":"2018-03-27T07:34:45.6578664Z","tags":{"ai.application.ver":"1.0.0.0","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"aspnet5c:2.1.1"},"data":{"baseType":"MessageData","baseData":{"ver":2,"message":"Executed DbCommand (22ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']\r\","severityLevel":"Information","properties":{"commandTimeout":"30","AspNetCoreEnvironment":"Development","commandType":"Text","DeveloperMode":"true","elapsed":"22","commandText":"SELECT CASE\r\n    WHEN EXISTS (\r\n        SELECT 1\r\n        FROM [Pies] AS [p])\r\n    THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)\r\nEND","CategoryName":"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command","{OriginalFormat}":"Executed DbCommand ({elapsed}ms) [Parameters=[{parameters}], CommandType='{commandType}', CommandTimeout='{commandTimeout}']{newLine}{commandText}"}}}}
>   The program '[13720] dotnet.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: Without more information, such as console logs, it's impossible to say with any certainty what the problem could be.

Comment: Which IDE are you using? Could it be that the newly created database is locked and you try to access it? Have you tried to `try/catch` the exception? If yes, post it here.

Comment: Maybe this thread can be of help: https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/844

Comment: 502.5 is essentially a critical error. Basically, your app is crashing on load, which also explains why debugging is stopping as well. Most likely, you're throwing an exception in Startup.cs, but there's not enough here to fully diagnose it.